# Fourier Transform of complex exponential $ \omega $ vs. $ 2 \pi f $

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

The Fourier Transform of a complex exponential is an impulse (or Dirac) function. Depending on how frequency is written ($ \omega $ or $ f $) we have two identical definitions of the same FT:

$$ \mathcal{F} \{ e^{j n \omega_0 t} \} = 2 \pi \cdot \delta(\omega - n \omega_0) $$

$$ \mathcal{F} \{ e^{j n 2 \pi f_0 t} \} = \delta(f - n f_0) $$

That implies

$$ \implies 2 \pi \cdot \delta(\omega - n \omega_0) = \delta(f - n f_0) $$

In my attempt to verify this, I expanded $ \omega $ into $ 2 \pi f $ and there was this $ 2 \pi $ factor inside and out of $ \delta $ that don't seem to cancel out:

$$ \begin{align} 2 \pi \cdot \delta(\omega - n \omega_0) &= 2 \pi \cdot \delta(2\pi f - n 2 \pi f_0) \\ &= 2 \pi \cdot \delta \big[2 \pi (f-nf_0) \big] \neq \delta(f-nf_0)  \; ??? \end{align} $$

Can someone help to proof these two equations and explain the intuition behind it? What does it mean to have a $ 2 \pi $ scaling factor on the x-axis if I transform $ f $ to $ \omega $?

Comment: If $a>1$ then $\delta(ax)$ is "narrower" than $\delta(x)$ making and integral smaller. The following identity holds generally:
$$\delta(ax) = \frac{1}{|a|} \delta(x).$$

Comment: @md2perpe how does the scaling factor $ a $ make $ \delta $ narrower? Actually my question sohuld be: what does $ \delta(ax) $ even mean? A delta function is $ 0 $ everywhere except for $ x=0 $ where amplitude goes to $ \infty $.  So $ \delta(ax) = \delta(x) = \infty $ for $ x=0 $, and for anywhere else on the x-axis $ \delta(ax) = \delta(x) = 0 $.  For example, if $ a=2, x=5 $ then $ \delta(ax) = \delta(2 \cdot 5) = 0 $ and $ \delta(x) = \delta(5) =0 $ as well. Hence, shouldn't $ \delta(ax) = \delta(x) $ instead?

Comment: You should learn a better definition of $\delta$ than $\delta(x)=\begin{cases}\infty & (x=0)\\0 & (x\neq 0)\end{cases}.$

Comment: But that was exactly why I had this question:

$$ \delta(x) =
\begin{cases}
\infty &\;(x=0)\\
0 &\;(x\neq0) 
\end{cases} $$

$$ \delta(ax) =
\begin{cases}
\infty &\;(x=0)\\
0 &\;(x\neq0) 
\end{cases} $$

$$ \implies \delta(ax) = \delta(x) $$

Comment: I wrote that you should learn a better definition than that one. That definition is not good. It doesn't say much about $\delta.$ Forget that pointwise definition! Use the definition in my answer instead; that is better, although not perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dirac $\delta$ distribution is better defined by
$\int \delta(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx = \phi(0)$
for every continuous function $\phi.$

With the distribution $a\delta(x),$ where $a\in\mathbb{R},$ we then mean that $$\int (a\delta)(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx = a \int \delta(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx = a\phi(0).$$

And $\delta(ax)$ we define by making a variable substitution:
$$
\int \delta(ax) \, \phi(x) \, dx
= \{ y := ax \}
= \int \delta(y) \, \phi(y/a) \, \frac{dy}{|a|}
= \frac{1}{|a|} \phi(0/a)
= \frac{1}{|a|} \phi(0)
= \int \frac{1}{|a|} \delta(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx,
$$
i.e. $\delta(ax) = \frac{1}{|a|} \delta(x)$ since the above is valid for all continuous functions $\phi.$

Comment: Thanks! How should I interpret $ \delta(ax) = {1 \over a} \delta(x) $? I can't relate how a scaled $ x $ could result in a scaled $ \delta $ and that the relationship only holds for $ x \neq 0 $ which otherwise would yield $ \delta(a \cdot 0) = \delta(0) $. And scaling a $ \delta $ function carries practically no meaning

Comment: @KMC. I defined $a\delta(x)$ in my answer. That explains how you shall interpret $\frac1a \delta(x).$ Also note that $\delta$ is a distribution, *not* a function. You cannot really take its value at one specific $x$. I decided to use a function notation anyways to not have you try to understand a better notation.

Comment: ah.. so it's better to treat $ \delta(x) $ as an operator for distribution rather than a function of itself that carries no particular meaning other than a shape

Comment: @KMC. Not an operator. It's rather a linear functional, i.e. a map that takes a function ($\phi$ in my answer) and returns a scalar ($\phi(0)$.